# update list of <select> from another <select multiple> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update a `<select>` element when I select one or multiple values from another `<select multiple>` using jQuery. Here's my multiple `select`:

```
<select class="form-control" multiple>
    <option value="1">company 1</option>
    <option value="2">company 2</option>
    <option value="3">company 3</option>
    <option value="4">company 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Improve your question please. Add code that you've tried to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for,

```js
$('select#first').change(function() {
  $("select#second option:not(:first-child)").remove();
  $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
    $("select#second").append($(this).clone());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="first" class="form-control" multiple>
  <option value="1">company 1</option>
  <option value="2">company 2</option>
  <option value="3">company 3</option>
  <option value="4">company 4</option>
</select>
<select name="second" id="second">
  <option value=''>Select 2</select>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this script https://jsfiddle.net/gpb5wx8h/5/

**Jquery:**

```
function chooseItems(item, placeholder){
        $(item).change(function() {
          var item = $(this);

          console.log(typeof(item.val()));
          if(typeof item.val() == 'object'){
            $.each(item.val(), function(i,v){
              var selectedItem = item.find('option[value="'+ v +'"]'),
                  selectedText = selectedItem.text();

              selectedItem.detach();
              $(placeholder).append('<option value="' + v +'">' + selectedText + '</option>')

            })
          }
      })
 }
$(document).ready(function() {
   chooseItems('.choose-role','.placeholder-role');
   chooseItems('.placeholder-role','.choose-role');
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control choose-role" multiple>
    <option value="1">company 1</option>
    <option value="2">company 2</option>
    <option value="3">company 3</option>
    <option value="4">company 4</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control placeholder-role" multiple>
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to update select options by fetching data from the server end regarding the selected values in multiple select box then you can perform ajax operation and insert the result to the another select box which is to be updated.

Comment: Perhaps you could post some code to show OP how to do this? "You can solve this by solving it" isn't very helpful